# Serve raw, dynamic html content from file in Django?

Tags: django

I can generate html from a file on the fly and return like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="text/html")
content = "".join(open(filename).readlines())
response._set_content(content)
return response
```

but is there a better, built in way, in Django 1.5?

Comment: You mean like using templates?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to serve static html content from your filesystem, then let your front server do the job (or use django's static.views but that's a waste of resources). If you want to dynamically generate html, then well, it's documented.

Comment: The content is not static, I am generating it on the fly. "It's documented" isn't really helpful; where? how?

Comment: Are the files stored locally on your file system, or somewhere else on the internet? If they are stored locally: do they always have the same location?

Comment: They are created locally, on the fly. They can be put in any location, but they can have different information every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is a better method for making a file available for download or viewing, short of streaming (which has some downsides, such as not having a known size).

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def serve_file(filename):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="text/html")
    for line in open(filename):
        response.write(line)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Django is an MVC framework (well, arguably it's MTV, but the basic principle is similar), so you should be [creating templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/) for that kind of task.

Comment: I use templates where appropriate, but I have an external system that generates HTML. The question is, how to integrate that into the Django framework?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your webserver to [serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/deployment/) directly.

If you absolutely have to do it through django you could use [static views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/).

Comment: The HTML is not static... it is generated on the fly by an outside-of-Django program.